# Get variables into outside the function

Tags: angularjs

I have one function, I am required to print the `lastlockerbalance` outside the function.

```
var getlockerbalance = function() {
    $http.get("php/selectLOCKERBALANCE.php").success(function(lockerbalance) {
        $scope.lockerbalance1 = lockerbalance;
        var lastlockerbalance = $scope.lockerbalance1[0].LOCKERBALANCE;
        console.log(lastlockerbalance);
    });
};
console.log(lastlockerbalance);
```

Showing error message as "lastlockerbalance is undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either return a `promise` and use `then()` or pass a callback to the function.

**Promise**

```
function getlockerbalance() {
     return $http.get("php/selectLOCKERBALANCE.php").success(function(lockerbalance) {
        $scope.lockerbalance1 = lockerbalance;
        var lastlockerbalance = $scope.lockerbalance1[0].LOCKERBALANCE;
        return lastlockerbalance;
    });
};

getlockerbalance().then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

**Callback**

```
var getlockerbalance = function(callback) {
    $http.get("php/selectLOCKERBALANCE.php").success(function(lockerbalance) {
        $scope.lockerbalance1 = lockerbalance;
        var lastlockerbalance = $scope.lockerbalance1[0].LOCKERBALANCE;
        callback(lastlockerbalance);
    });
};

function printBalance(balance) {
    console.log(balance);
}

getlockerbalance(printBalance);
```

Comment: Your promise example needs to assign to `lastlockerbalance` in the outer scope: `lastlockerbalance = getlockerbalance()` though it might be better to give it a different name to distinguish the promise from the value.

Comment: yeah, I refactored. but he should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `.success()` callback won't even have been called by the time your second `console.log()` function is called, in fact the request `$http.get()` call won't even send the request until after the `getlockerbalance()` function returns.

What you need to do is move the code that uses the value inside the callback.

Comment: I do agree with you, but (window).lastlockerbalance will be set (not at the time the OP is printing it). Of course, it should be moved inside a callback.